# wpa_supplicant.conf with two network cards not working when wpa-roam

Tags: networking, raspbian

I need to use two different network dongles in a Raspberry Pi (one realtek and one tplink) for two different networks. My wpa_supplicant.conf looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev

network={
    id_str="id1"
    ssid="ssid1"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    eap=PEAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    identity="identity"
    anonymous_identity="identity"
    password="password"
    phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    priority=1
}

network={
    id_str="id2"
    ssid="ssid2"
    scan_ssid=0
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=TKIP
    psk="password"
    priority=0
}
```

and my interface file looks like this:

```
auto lo

iface default inet dhcp
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.103.146
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.103.254

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface id2 inet static
    address 192.168.0.199
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface id1 inet dhcp
```

I can not make the two interfaces work at the same time. When I make ifup wlan0, it connects correctly, but after that when I make ifup wlan1, wlan0 disconnects and wlan1 connects correctly, and viceversa.

I tried configuring one as wpa-conf and both connects correctly, but I NEED to have both in wpa-roam mode in order to reconnect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finnaly! I figure it out!

This shell script cause two adaptor "wpa-roam" never work!
So fix it yourself :)
The script's description:

---

## If an ifplugd managed interface is brought up, disconnect any

## wpa-roam managed interfaces so that only one "roaming" interface

## remains active on the system.

---

Fix it yourself:

```
sudo vim /etc/wpa_supplicant/action_wpa.sh
```

Comment out the follow line

```
#if wpa_action "${IFACE}" check; then
#       wpa_cli -i "${IFACE}" "${COMMAND}"
#fi
```

That's it!
You've got two adaptor roaming work now!

Comment: Does anyone know what is the reason to have only one "roaming" interface?